# How does this code work? Is there a different way to write it to make it more readable?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning python and I found out you can use .apply() to apply a function to a column. I am confused as to why you can use cols[0] in this scenario. When I try running df[0] I get an error. However, with the way I am passing data to the function, I'd expect to get a result. Why is cols[0] acceptable but df[0] is not?

```
def fills_na(cols):
    Age = cols[0] # i dont understand why this works. When running df_new[0] I get an error
    Pclass = cols[1]
    if pd.isnull(Age):
        if Pclass == 1:
            return 37
        elif Pclass == 2:
            return 29
        else:
            return 24
    else:
        return Age
# then this baby calls it
df['Age'] = df[['Age','Pclass']].apply(fills_na, axis = 1)
```

Comment: `df` isn't passed to `cols`, individual rows as `pd.Series` objects are.

Comment: It's tough to know for sure what you did exactly that gave you the errors you're referring to. It would help if you could add that information in with some example dataframes. However, if i had to make a few assumptions and take a guess: note that the apply here is acting on a "dataframe" with "axis = 1". I highly suspect you either used apply on a series, did not pass an axis, or both of those.